# SVG drawing for live waveform; erase the drawing by coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am drawing a waveform using "path" in SVG; after the frame width is over; I want to erase the existing wave by a small length and draw a new wave.So; the output should look like continous waves being drawn one after another with a delay between them.
How can I erase a small section of coordinates in SVG.

Is there any method like clearRect() (for Canvas) in SVG?

Comment: could you post your code so far? IMHO, the solution is really dependent on how you wrote it.

Comment: Just delete the elements or path you created.